# Linq, Where Extension Method, Lambda Expressions, and Bool's

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Greetings, I am having some issues with using a bool operation within a Where clause extension method of an IQueryable object obtained using Linq to Entities.  The first example is showing what does work using Bool1 as the operation I need to move to a where clause extension method.  The second example is what doesn't work after the change. Bool1 is is completely ignored and doesn't impact the results.

Example 1:

```
var results =
     from a in context.aTable1
     where a.Bool1 == false && a.Bool2  == false
     select new
     {
           Column1 = a.Column1
           Bool1 = a.Bool1
           Bool2 = a.Bool2
     };

results.Where(l => l. Column1.Contains(fooString));
```

Example 2:

```
var results =
     from a in context.aTable1
     where a.Bool2  == false
     select new
     {
           Column1 = a.Column1
           Bool1 = a.Bool1
           Bool2 = a.Bool2
     };

results.Where(l => l.Bool1 == false);
results.Where(l => l. Column1.Contains(fooString));
```

These are over simplified examples, however I hope they show what I am trying to do.  The where extension methods are in a different method and are the reason they cannot be done when I am creating the original query.

I have tried the following other ways of doing the same thing with that where clause:

```
results.Where(l => !l.Bool1);
results.Where(l => l.Bool1.Equals(false));
```

They have the same effect which is nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second and third queries are getting "lost" because you're not assigning them to anything. Try something like this instead:

```
var results = from a in context.aTable1
              where !a.Bool2
              select new
              {
                  Column1 = a.Column1
                  Bool1 = a.Bool1
                  Bool2 = a.Bool2
              };

results = results.Where(l => !l.Bool1);
results = results.Where(l => l.Column1.Contains(fooString));
```

Comment: DOH!!! I feel stupid, I can't believe I didn't notice that I forgot to assign it.  Thanks for the the help you rock!!

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the results of your queries to anything. Each call to `Where()` returns the results of that query, which you'll need to do something with.

In your case, you have a few options (all of which produce the same final result):

- If you want to do something with the non-Bool1 results, you can choose to keep them around:

  ```
  var notBool1 = results.Where(l => !l.Bool1);
  var query = notBool1.Where(l => l.Column1.Contains(fooString));
  ```
- You can chain `Where()` calls together:

  ```
  var query = results.Where(l => !l.Bool1)
                     .Where(l => l.Column1.Contains(fooString));
  ```
- This is probably the fastest, although perhaps not by much:

  ```
  var query = results.Where(l => !lBool1 && l.Column1.Contains(fooString));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
results.Where(l => l.Bool1 == false && l.Column1.Contains(fooString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Where` queries *return* a collection, they do not modify the collection they were called on.

```
var numbers = new int [] { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0); // numbers still contains 1,2,3,4,5,6
var evens = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0); // evens contains 2,4,6, numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6
numbers = numbers.Where(x => x % 2 == 0); // numbers now contains 2,4,6
```